# IONIC 5 capacitor build android error : Execution failed for task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework

I get the below error when I want to run my ionic app on android studio by using cmd -> **ionic capacitor build android**
Can teach me how to solve the below errors so that I can run my application on android studio?
Thank You.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:..\node_modules\@capacitor\android\capacitor\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@2cce4302) before task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: what version of `java` are you using?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Version 8 Update 291 (build 1.8.0_291-b10)

Answer (score 4):

Issue solved by updating the Gradle in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You must set version of Compile Sdk Version and Builds tools Version in File -> Project Structure -> app . set the values and it build self.